# "POST" with HttpWebRequest not working correctly

Tags: c#, xml, http, post, uwp

I'm trying to post some xml to http://api.opensubtitles.org:80/xml-rpc, but it's not working. If I use https://www.hurl.it/, I get the response I'm expecting, but not with my C#. This is the xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>LogIn</methodName>
<param>
    <value><string></string></value>
</param>
<param>
    <value><string></string></value>
</param>
<param>
    <value><string></string></value>
</param>
<param>
    <value>
        <string>OSTestUserAgent</string>
    </value>
</param>
```

And this is my C#:

```
    public static async Task<string> HttpRequest(string xml)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.opensubtitles.org:80/xml-rpc");
        request.Method = "POST";

        using (StreamWriter dataStream = new StreamWriter(await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()))
        {
            dataStream.Write(xml);
            dataStream.Dispose();
        }
        string result = null;
        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(result);
        return result;
    }
```

I receive a "parse error. not well formed" from the server. What on earth is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put the parameters list in a `<params></params>` tag as per the [XMLRPC specification](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec.html). This code works just fine:

```
var myxml =
    @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <methodCall>
        <methodName>LogIn</methodName>
        <params>
            <param>
                <value><string></string></value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <value><string></string></value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <value><string></string></value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <value>
                    <string>OSTestUserAgent</string>
                </value>
            </param>
        </params>
    </methodCall>";

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.opensubtitles.org:80/xml-rpc");
request.Method = "POST";

using (var dataStream = new StreamWriter(await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()))
{
    dataStream.Write(myxml);
    dataStream.Dispose();
}

string result = null;

using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
{
    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}


Debug.WriteLine(result);
```

[.Net Fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bYGI5g)